# In what format should I store data of a large php form with few dynamic fields

Tags: php, mysql, forms, dynamic, field

I have a large php form with dynamic fields and there can be additional fields added after releasing into production. How do I store this large data into mysql database using php so that it can handle dynamic fields and additional fields. Example of a form can be seen in the link below.

http://form.jotform.me/form/50655815937465

The above link doesn't contain dynamic fields for now but it may contain later.

The main form is huge so we divided into different sections. Need to handle this as well. Also need a save draft concept where the user can save the data and load it later when he gets a chance to complete it.

Comment: What are you asking, if you should use a database or not?

Comment: What is a dynamc field? A field you can add without editing the code?

Comment: Dynamic field in the sense, when you select an option a subform appears based on the selection. Those subforms can contain anything based on the input provided by the user. @German

Comment: @developerwjk : No am asking about how to store the form. It can be mysql or filestorage.? which ones better for it.

Comment: @NareshGhanate, you don't store a form, you use it to input data. You store the data you get after its submission then. And there is logic in between.

Checkout some manuals on some either CMS or MVC-frameworks tutorials. The former are more ready-to-use out-of-the-box, the letter have more freedom and flexibility.

Comment: Database is always better for data. File storage is better for files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of different ways to handle this, but I'll make a simple recommendation

**For the static fields**

- Create a column in your table for each static field
- Save each static field submission in the corresponding column

**For dynamic fields**

- Create an array of dynamic values and call `serialize` on it
- Store the serialized value in a single long text column in the database
- To read the values, you will have to call `unserialize` on it

---

**Pros**

- Easy to implement
- Ability to filter data based on static inputs
- Only uses one extra column for dynamic inputs
- Supports a large amount of dynamic form inputs

**Cons**

- Difficult to filter data based on dynamic inputs

---

**Alternative solutions**

These solutions are significantly more robust but require a much deeper understanding. I'll leave these here for you to research on your own.

- [Entity Attribute Value (EAV) model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)
- [Document-oriented database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database)

Comment: Superb. You solved it like a piece of a cake. Will surely implement this. thanks @maček